# Cannot align the adjacent edges of inline-block elements to touch

Tags: html, css, margin, display

I just tried using css `display: inline-block` in my code to create 3 side by side columns. I set the `margin` and `padding` to 0, but the edges of the columns are not touching (I bordered the elements to visualize the effect); its like there is some default `margin` given to `display: inline-block`.
How can one align the edges of `display: inline-block` elements without using guess values of -ve `margin` or absolute positioning.

```
<div>
  <div style='display: inline-block;'>apple</div>
  <div style='display: inline-block;'>ball</div>
  <div style='display: inline-block;'>cat</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share your code for better understanding

Comment: Please can you share a code snipet so that we can see what you mean.

Comment: Could it be a whitespace problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `font-size: 0` to the parent element, and then declare your default `font-size` on the children.

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
li { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
    background: #f33;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
    background: #3f3;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    background: #33f;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>element 1</li>
        <li>element 2</li>
        <li>element 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: If you don't set a new font size to the children, these will be invisible (they have font-size:0px)

Comment: Brilliant! The edges are aligned, but the text within the children have disappeared.

Comment: It seems I must set the new font-size to use absolute values like 'px', and not values like 'em'